# How to make a LED flash on an Arduino using c++ but without using any function besides millis()

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to make the LED flash on my arduino without using any function other than millis() within setup() and loop(). Here is what I have so far:

```
long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 1000;

void setup()
{
   DDRB = DDRB | B11111100;
}
void loop()
{
   if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= interval)
      {
      if ( PORTB == B00000000)
          PORTB = B00100000;
      else
          PORTB = B00000000; 
      }
}
```

All it does is make the light go on and stay on though. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Are you changing `previousMillis` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't resetting `previousMillis` at all so once `(millis() - previousMillis) >= interval` is true, it will stay true forever.

What this means is your light will be flashing on and off so fast, it will appear as though its permanently on.

Add: `previousMillis = millis()` to the end of your loop() function.